# How to change Current Date to MinguoDate in Java8?

Tags: java-8

I have to use the **`MinguoDate`** in my program that I am writing in Java8.

I have current date in string format:

> **`String currentDate="2018-07-20";`**

Can anyone tell me how to convert **`current date`** to the **`Minguo date`** using java8

**Note:** MinguoDate calendar system is primarily used in Taiwan (Republic of China)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the string into a `LocalDate` instance and then put the result of that into the `MinguoDate.from` method to yield a `MinguoDate`.

```
MinguoDate minguoDate = MinguoDate.from(LocalDate.parse(currentDate));
```